# Apply a custom template layout to Liferay 6.2 homepage

Tags: templates, layout, themes, liferay-6

I'm trying to create AND apply a custom template layout to my homepage in Liferay 6.2, but impossible.

First of all, I created a my custom template layout. After redeploying, I tried to find how to apply it, but no way. I can only do it on new pages. For my home page, niet.

Comment: Which liferay version you are using?

Comment: Nobody has this problem ?

Comment: I have tried applying new layout to /web/guest/home page, and I was able to apply that layout